# Correct indexed item is not being removed from LocalStorage

Tags: arrays, angular, object, local-storage

I am finding that this code:

```
deleteImage(image ){
    const index = this.selectedGallery.indexOf(image);
    this.selectedGallery.splice(index, 1);
    localStorage.setItem('selectedImages', JSON.stringify(this.selectedGallery));
}
```

This is where the localstorage array is set:

```
if (localStorage) {
   var selectedImages;
   if (!localStorage['selectedImages']) selectedImages = [];
   else selectedImages = JSON.parse(localStorage['selectedImages']);
   if (!(selectedImages instanceof Array)) selectedImages = [];
   selectedImages.push(imageFile);
   localStorage.setItem('selectedImages', JSON.stringify(selectedImages));
   his.storageSubject.next(selectedImages);
}
```

is removing the last item of the localstorage array and not the indexed item I am trying to remove.

Not sure why, as any precedents I've looked at on here seem to use this way of doing it.

Is there another way that anyone knows of?

Comment: can you show what does your `image` variable contains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is bcs it's not finding the image in array and following line return `-1` as index instead of actual index

```
 const index = this.selectedGallery.indexOf(image);
```

So passing correct index should work

Comment: actually, as it happens, images doesn't contain anything. I will post up where I am setting the selectedImages array.

Comment: @Apex so if your image doesn't contains anything how it will find an index in array it will always return -1

Comment: if you can create stackblitz sample of your problem that can help better to resolve your problem

Comment: yes, you are right. I was working late last night and wasn't passing the image object into the deleteImage() click event in the view.  (click)="deleteImage(image)" - seems to be working now.

Comment: so you'r able to get correct index using `this.selectedGallery.indexOf(image)`?

Comment: yes, looks like it. I will test with a larger array but looks good so far. I've ticked your input. thank you for helping me.